# Set Data table to contain nodes of xml like data member of data grid VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagrid, datatable

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <document>
    <sentences>
      <sentence id="1">
        <tokens>
           <token id="7">
            <word>founded</word>
            <lemma>found</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>72</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>79</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>VBN</POS>
            <NER>O</NER>
          </token>
          <token id="8">
            <word>in</word>
            <lemma>in</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>80</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>82</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>IN</POS>
            <NER>O</NER>
          </token>
          <token id="9">
            <word>1891</word>
            <lemma>1891</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>83</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>87</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>CD</POS>
            <NER>DATE</NER>
            <NormalizedNER>1891</NormalizedNER>
            <Timex tid="t1" type="DATE">1891</Timex>
          </token>
          <token id="10">
            <word>.</word>
            <lemma>.</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>87</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>88</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>.</POS>
            <NER>O</NER>
          </token>
        </tokens>
      </sentence>
    </sentences>
  </document>
</root>
```

Now I've placed a Datagrid on my Form1 and added the following code:

Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

```
ds.ReadXml("input.txt.xml")

With Me.DataGridView1

    .DataSource = ds

    .DataMember = "token"

End With
```

And it looks great.   I can see all the tokens in my XML populated the rows and columns of the Datagrid.

But I don't want the data in the datagrid.  I just want it in the datatable....

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()


        dt.ReadXml("input.txt.xml")
```

Then what command like the   .DataMember = "token"   can I issue or do I need to copy it into a new datatable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it via a dataview:

```
Dim myDT As DataTable
Dim myDV As DataView

myDV = ds.Tables(4).DefaultView
myDT = myDV.ToTable
```

If anyone knows how to go directly or replace the (4) with "token" - because it is the 4th table in the dataset then let me know.